# Google maps API 3 help needed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using a google maps API 3 for my application.

So what I want to do is next. 
When page is loading I will get an array of positions in this format:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
```

Firs I want to add marker to each of this positins

```
var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });
```

Picture that goes on the marker:

```
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/truck3.png",
        new google.maps.Size(32.0, 37.0),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(16.0, 18.0)
    );
  var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/shadow-truck3.png",
        new google.maps.Size(51.0, 37.0),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(16.0, 18.0)
    );

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    shadow: shadow,
    title: 'Click to zoom'
  });
```

And this should zoom all the markers that are initialized in the center of the screen but only once at the beginning later on center is not used as user may fish to look something else on the map.

I want a markers to be moving all the time so maybe I need to add some event handler to fetch new position all the time?

Then comes the part when you click on the marker, you got zoomed and marker is still moving ( getting new position ) but now I need to use that ID that I will send in the php array so I can call some php function with that parameter.

After that when user clicks on the button which is on the side I want to be able to come at the beginning of my request and that means loaded markers in the center of the screen.

Part with the click:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(13);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
    // 1 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
    // marker.
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
    }, 1000);
  });
  });
}
```

So basically I told you everything that I want to achieve I am sure that a lot of you made the same thing. These are part of the code from a lot of sources I need to make them work together and add some smaller new features as I wrote above.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe there is a lot of text but I think request is pretty small if you know what you are doing :)

Comment: Duplicate of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10931109/1314132. Please take a look at the new edit I have added to the latest changes in your original question and see if that helps. Not giving you a hard time, but it makes more sense to add clarity to the original question, not to create a duplicate question with added clarity.

Comment: I think there's too much here for free help (quite apart from duplicating another question instead of refining it). 1: Zoom to markers. 2: Refresh periodically. 3: Marker click or button click or both [not enough data to know what you want here]. Each of those should be asked sequentially in separate questions, building on what has gone before, and showing what code you have tried in order to achieve the objective.

Comment: Can somone give me an idea how to make the bellow code to work when receiving an array(lat,lng,serial_number) As this code is working for some other values. I'll have a php that will return me a json format as this code has it. but only I need and id of an marker to have a serial number. Any answer is a good answer! please help and you can get 100 points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it sounds like you are retrieving the `locations` variable with a database query repeated every few seconds. In this demo I'm using JSON to retrieve the data, and update the location or create the marker if it doesn't already exist.

http://freezoo.alwaysdata.net/truck2.html

```
    function updateTrucks() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "gettruck.php",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert("Error: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(data) {
        for(var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
          if(trucks.hasOwnProperty(data.results[i].id)) {
            // update position
            trucks[data.results[i].id].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(data.results[i].lat),
              parseFloat(data.results[i].lng)));
            trucks[data.results[i].id].speed = data.results[i].speed;
          }
          else {
            // create new marker
            trucks[data.results[i].id] = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(data.results[i].lat),
                parseFloat(data.results[i].lng)),
              title: data.results[i].name,
              id: data.results[i].id
            });
```

In your application the database will get updated by some means, here, the database is static and movement (for the demo) is artificially created with PHP `rand`, so every few seconds the markers appear in different locations.

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo '{ "results" : [ ';

$gettruck_result = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `truck`");
$result_array = array();

foreach($gettruck_result as $row) {
  $newlat = $row['lat'] + (0.0025 * rand(-3,3));
  $newlng = $row['lng'] + (0.0025 * rand(-3,3));

  $speed = $row['speed'] + rand(1,8);

  $row_object = '{';
  $row_object .= '"id": "' . $row['id'] . '", ';
  $row_object .= '"speed": "' . $speed . '", ';
  $row_object .= '"name": "' . $row['name'] . '", ';
  $row_object .= '"lat": "' . $newlat . '", ';
  $row_object .= '"lng": "' . $newlng . '"';
  $row_object .= '}';    
  $result_array[] = $row_object;
}

$result_str = implode(", ", $result_array);
echo $result_str;
echo " ] }";
```

Tracking a marker is done with two listeners:

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(trucks[data.results[i].id], 'position_changed', function() {
          if(typeof tracked !== "undefined") {
            if(this.id == tracked.id) {
              map.panTo(this.getPosition());
              $("#speed").val(this.speed);
            } 
          } 
        });         

        google.maps.event.addListener(trucks[data.results[i].id], 'click', function() {
          $("#trackedId").val(this.id);
          map.setZoom(13);
          map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
          tracked = this;
        });
```

Comment: hi this is a really nice code. Sort of what I need. So I would like to fetch data from mysql database every approximately 10sec. The only data I am getting from database is Latitude and Longitude but I think direction can be determine if coordinate is starting with minus or plus..Anyway thumb up for your effort. Do I need to have a directions? or marker will be moved anyway to that position?

Comment: Hi can you please send me an email to denonth.jesus@gmail.com I have some questions for you

Comment: Let's keep it in Stack Overflow, so others can help too. You see, I'm not at all good with PHP and it seems to be important in your project.

Comment: Do I need to have this side of the world direction? Or I can just give a new coordinate and it will move. btw code stops when you press reset should it be able to continue to show all of the markers and how they move? I need to get a Lat,Lng and serial_number from the mysql database.

Comment: The north, south, east and west were just meant as examples. The PHP file I wrote receives the 'dir' parameter and responds with a certain movement for the choice. Reset puts everything back in its original place and I did make everything stop on purpose. When you access the database, don't you need to pass an ID to begin with?

Comment: No I am fetching always the last data from the database.this was example with an id input but I will use serial nmber for fetching some values from certain marker whenyou click on it. For example you click on the marker and I will pas serail number and get the speed and write it so user can see it

Comment: In my answer I use `.id` for each marker, you can use that value when the marker is clicked to pass to the database query.

Comment: Can you help me with following. I want to have and id sent from database. So how would your code look like if I am only sending data from php script into the javascript file. Here you are sending something and retrieving something. Can you please make me an example where I can get lat,lng and serialnumber from database ( you don need to do json part) and then make this received serial as id for each truck.

Comment: I don't know how your app is supposed to work so I can't give a good answer. Is the database query meant to update all truck positions at once? What about the `locations` variable? Is the last index the serial number (1-5)? Do you keep sending the same query to the database? How is the database itself updated for the movement to happen?

Comment: So your code is doing what I will have in my app. I will fetch data on the same way you do except I will have serial number variable. Yes last index in the query will be the serial number. Query will be made in the php so I will only call php function or php script to give me back resoults. I will receive lastresults for all the cars at the same time as you have `var locations` I will fill it with the last positions frequently every 10 sec. Database is filled constantly with the new data every 5-7sec so we don't need to worry about database. IS this what you need to give me a hand in this

Comment: I rewrote most of the code, I think it's simpler if the database query returns all trucks' locations at once. The answer is updated with a new demo link.

Comment: Hi yes database is returning all truck's location at once. I'll try your code to see if I can make it work to my own

Comment: Hi this is great example, I have only one more question. Where can I save the speed value when I am retrieve it from the JSON. So I can use that certain speed value when I click on the certain marker. Please help

Comment: The trucks' speeds can be stored in the `trucks[data.results[i].id].speed` property, the same way the id is stored when the marker is created. The difference is when you repeatedly query the database to update the marker positions, you also add `trucks[data.results[i].id].speed = data.results[i].speed` which is a value from the database/JSON.

Comment: Please look at the question I have put the code that I have tried

Comment: @denonth I updated the demo and answer, first the database has a new static speed column with random increments added with PHP. Then, when the AJAX is called, this speed is saved to each truck. When updating the truck position, the newest speed is displayed in the sidebar.

Comment: Hmm I have sort of the problem. I am loading one time speed successfully then it is always the same value its not changing. Any idea?

Comment: Doesn't it get the value from your database? I'm not sure how that is supposed to work, do you use JSON also? If the position gets updated make sure to update speed also, and update the textbox (or HTML element)

Comment: Yes I am using JSON, code is same as yours. I mean I am having that line in the update marker. And position is changing, and json in validated format. Marker is moving but the values is received once and it's not changing later on. I just put the print into the trackerid html textbox that was used to show the id

Comment: Did you put this line `trucks[data.results[i].id].speed = data.results[i].speed;` next to `setPosition`? (where the marker is updated, not created)? Is the database updating the speed correctly?

Comment: let us [CONTINUE IN THE CHAT ROOM](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12648/discussion-between-denonth-and-lilina)

Answer (score 0):

This file [Geocoder.htm](http://www.calvert.ch/download/Geocoder.htm) contains all the code necessary to achieve what you trying to do (list of clickable icons with IDs and actions attached, etc.).

Just uncomment lines 449-460 and you can see how it works.

You're welcome to take the source and use it as you see fit, it's open-source.

Comment: Ok I'll see what you got. Thank you

Comment: Is this your script? How come I didn't find it if it is open source :) and I searched a lot

Comment: hmm I checked the code. Wow it's a lot of code. Basically this is not what I need. I mean maybe it is but I don't know where to start. So what I need Sir is next: At the start of the page I need to collect data as in this commented lines but different values. Then I need them to start moving as I retrieve every X sec last values from database. And when I click on the certain marker it zooms I need to be able to read other values that I passed to this marker to be read and presented. Any idea is good thank you

Comment: Is there any email to contact you in private? I really need some help

Comment: Yes, I wrote it. 90% of the Javascript you need to solve your problem is in the code I supplied. I'm afraid I can't do the last 10% for you >;-)